# How to set up a windows service to run on system shut-down by using the command line

Tags: windows, batch-file, service, cmd, command-line

Although there is plenty of info about how to set up a windows service to run on boot by using just the command line (`sc config`), i can't find an analogous command to set a service to run on windows shutdown. I need this set-up to happen automatically, preferably without human interaction - hence why a command-line approach would be perfect, which could be included in an installation script.

Is this possible to achieve?

Comment: Can you explain your task a little? because it seems odd to start a service, at the time when your system is in the process of closing everything. In addition what's preventing you from using Group Policy for this task?

Comment: Windows Task Scheduler has an option to do that. You could have it run `net start servicename`

Comment: @Compo Basically, in our job we have to click a web button at the start and end of our shift, and I always forget to do it - so I have developed a jnode app which clicks the button automatically, and I plan to execute it on my computer start-up and shutdown (which is the first and last thing to do at work, after all). After setting it as a service I have successfully made it execute on system start, and I was just wondering if I could do the same at shutdown (although executing a script on shutdown could work too I guess).

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a windows service for this.
You can just create a new task in the windows tasks planner for it.

- To open it, hit  key and type "tasks".
- Configure the task to start your executable/cmd/bat/ps1 file
- Configue the task to be triggered by "User session disconnection" (alternatively you can set a trigger to a windows event, but you need to find out the event id in the event log)

You're done.